# Linked List Merge Sort

Tags: c++, recursion, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a merge sort for a liked list, but when I test it, it returns a list of just the smallest item and then it seems to cut out the rest of the numbers in the list. Here is some of my code: Can any one point me in the right direction of my error?

```
    ListNode* ListP::merge(ListNode* head1, ListNode* head2)
    {
        if (head1 == NULL)
            return head1;
        else if (head2 == NULL)
            return head2;
        else if (head1->getItem() < head2->getItem())
        {
            head1->next = (merge(head1->next, head2));
            return head1;
        }
        else
        {
            head2->next = (merge(head2->next, head1));
            return head2;
        }

    }

    ListNode* ListP::mergesort(ListNode * theHead, int size)
    {
        int leftSize = size / 2;

        int rightSize = size - leftSize;
        int i = 0;
        if (theHead == NULL)
            return NULL ;
        else if (theHead->next == NULL)
            return theHead;

        ListNode* slow = theHead;
        ListNode* fast = theHead->next;
        while (fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            if (fast != NULL)
            {
                slow = slow->next;
                fast = fast->next;
            }
        }
        ListNode* ptr2 = slow->next;
        slow->next = NULL;
        slow = NULL;
        return merge(mergesort(theHead, leftSize), mergesort(ptr2, rightSize));
    }

    void ListP::sort_mergesort()
    {
        ListNode* ptr = head;
        head = mergesort(head, size);

    }
```

Comment: `if (head1 == NULL)` should return `head2`. But you return NULL. What is the point of returning NULL?

Comment: Note that although the size of each sub-list is calculated, it's never used in the code, so it's not needed (or use size/2 for the number of loops to advance slow pointer and never use the fast pointer). Not using a size parameter would be more generic. Also a top down merge sort for a list is relatively slow due to all the scanning of sub-lists to split the lists. A bottom up oriented merge sort would be much faster.